# Bubble sort in C (for strings)

Tags: c, strings, sorting

What do you think of this bubble sorting function in C, for a string array? I would like to improve the readability, performance, and any good practices.

```
void         sort_entries(char **entries, int reverse)
{
    char     **next;
    char     **previous;
    char     *t;
    int      value;

    previous = tab;
    while (*(next = previous + 1))
    {
        value = strcasecmp(*previous, *next);
        if ((!reverse && value > 0)
            || (reverse && value < 0))
        {
            t = *previous;
            *previous = *next;
            *next = t;
            previous = entries;
            continue ;
        }
        previous++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Portability**
The function `strcasecmp()` is a POSIX standard and not a in the C programming standard as pointed out in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127260/strcasecmp-a-non-standard-function). Therefore the `sort_entries()` function may not compile or link on some systems. It would be better if the program that contained the `sort_entries()` function also contained a version of `strcasecmp()`.

**Performance**
Generally a bubble sort will be implemented as nested loops, the inner loop going over the whole input list to perform as many swaps as possible in a single pass. This implementation restarts at the beginning after a single swap requiring more passes. There is no performance improvement by this single loop over the nested loop implementation, and there may be a performance hit.

If the code swapped the pointers rather than the strings themselves there might be an improvement in the performance.

**Variable Scope**
It is better from a maintainability perspective and overall code comprehension to create variables as needed rather than create all the variables at the top of the function. It would be better if the variables `t`, `next` and `value` were defined within the loop rather than at the top of the function. The variables `t` and `next` are only needed within the if statement.